# C# .Take() in Java

Tags: java, c#, java-stream

I'm a C# Developer and recently starting get into Java development and here I have a question. Did Java have any build in method that doing the same thing with C# `.Take()`?

C# example:

```
int diffNo = 1;
someNumber.OrderBy(x => x.someNumber).Take(diffNo).ToList();
```

Java example:

```
someNumber.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object::getSomeNumber)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So now for Java part I only able to do sorting but don't know is there method can use to replace `.Take()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream`s have a [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)) method, used to truncate a stream to *up to* the number of elements you provide as an argument.

So, assuming `diffNo` is a number, you can call it like this

```
someNumber.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SomeClass::getSomeNumber))
          .limit(diffNo)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```